# How to add a new custom instruction in the RISCV instruction set

Tags: riscv

From many days I've been trying to simulate new custom instructions using the RISV ISA simulator but haven't been successful in creating a new instruction and compiling it with the riscv assembler. I tried adding my own new opcode in risk-tools/riscv-opcodes/opcodes. I tried creating a custom opcode to do the function of ADD then replaced ADD with my custom instruction in the assembly code but the assembler failed to compile it saying instruction not found. Also when I'm trying to use the built in custom instructions custom0,1,2 I'm always getting the error of invalid operands.

Comment: I used the resources in the risk.org website on how to add a new instruction.

Comment: You will need to modify both the assembler and the simulator as well to support your new instruction.

Comment: I modified both spike, and rebuilt risk gnu toolchain after adding my instruction in binutils

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the following tutorial on how to add new instructions to the RISCV compiler: https://nitish2112.github.io/post/adding-instruction-riscv/

However, some of the steps have minor changes probably due to the recent updates to the compiler, so I will state the steps again with the updated changes in this answer. **I will assume the path to the working directory that we are using is `~/dir/`** .
Let's say we will add a modulo instruction similar to the tutorial. The modulo instruction and its semantic according to the above tutorial are:

```
mod r1, r2, r3

R[r1] = R[r2] % R[r3]
```

**Step 0**: cd to your working directory which I will call `~/dir/`:

```
cd ~/dir/
```

**Step 1**: Clone the RISCV-GNU-Toolchain into your working directory (or `~/dir/` as we called earlier) if you have not done this already. To do so, you can use the command:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain.git
```

**Step 2**: Install and build the riscv tools using the following commands.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools.git
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
$ export RISCV=/path/to/install/riscv/toolchain
$ ./build.sh
```

**Step 3**: open the file `~/dir/riscv-tools/riscv-opcodes/opcodes` and add the following line:

```
mod     rd rs1 rs2 31..25=1  14..12=0 6..2=0x1A 1..0=3
```

**Explanation** of this line: The modulo instruction that we are trying to add has three registers: the destination register, source register 1, and source register 2. This means that this instruction follows the R-type format according to the RISCV manual found here: https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf

Looking at the R-type format in the picture below, bits 31 to 25 define FUNCT7 and bits 14 to 12 define FUNCT3. Now, I am not sure why this is different than the manual but bits 6 to 2 are the opcode and not 6 to 0. I am sure there is a reason but I couldn't figure it out yet.

Now comparing this information with the line that we added, we've added the modulo instruction with FUNCT7 to be 0x01, FUNCT3 to be 0x0, and the opcode to be 0x1A. This is how the tutorial wants to define the opcode, FUNCT3, and FUNCT7 for this instruction. You can definitely change these numbers if you want but you have to make sure that the opcode, FUNCT7, and FUNCT3 that you choose are not the same as any other instruction. At least one of the three of these should be different compared to another instruction. For example, two instructions may have the same opcode and FUNCT7 but they have a different FUNCT3: this is valid!

[image]

**Step 4**: cd to the directory `~/dir/riscv-tools/riscv-opcodes` and run the following command.

```
cat opcodes-pseudo opcodes opcodes-rvc opcodes-rvc-pseudo opcodes-custom | ./parse-opcodes -c > ~/temp.h
```

**Step 5**: open the file `~/temp.h` (probably using the command `vi`. Then search for `MATCH_MOD`. You should find the following two lines:

```
#define MATCH_MOD 0x200006b
#define MASK_MOD 0xfe00707f
```

**Copy** these two lines and add them to the file `~/dir/riscv-gnu-toolchain/riscv-binutils/include/opcode/riscv-opc.h`

**Explanation of MATCH_MOD and MASK_MOD**: the instruction is decoded using the following formula: `((insn ^ op->match) & op->mask) == 0;`. So, the MASK_MOD and MATCH_MOD are used exactly as shown in the formula by the compiler. When the result gives 0 then this means it matches the modulo instruction and this is how it is decoded! -this is as far as I understand, someone else may try to add to this if they have more knowledge:)

**Step 6 (Note: this step is OUTDATED in the tutorial in the link above)** : Open the file `~/dir/riscv-gnu-toolchain/riscv-binutils/opcodes/riscv-opc.c` and add the following line:

```
{"mod",   0, INSN_CLASS_I, "d,s,t",         MATCH_MOD, MASK_MOD, match_opcode, 0 },
```

**Step 7**: Build the riscv gnu toolchain and you are done! Follow the instructions on this link to build the toolchain: https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain

As an example, to build the 64-bit compiler on linux you may use the following commands:

```
$ cd ~/dir/riscv-gnu-toolchain
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure prefix=/opt/riscv64
$ sudo make linux
$ export PATH=/opt/riscv64/bin/:$PATH
```

**Note** that building the compiler may take a while (it takes almost an hour on my machine).

**Step 8**: You are done!! you can now test it as shown in the tutorial! You can add the modulo instruction as an inline assembly and then you may compile your code. You can only compile the code at this point. In order to run your code, you have to add the instruction to the simulator as well. I only know how to add the instruction in GEM5 so I am going to share this. Note that the steps about GEM5 in the tutorial are almost wrong because they are not using the right opcode/FUNCT7/FUNCT3 that they defined earlier in step 3 for some reason.

**Adding the instruction to GEM5**

**Step 0**: clone gem5 to your working directory using the following command:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/gem5/gem5.git
```

**Step 1**: Open the file `~/dir/gem5/src/arch/riscv/isa/decoder.isa`. Find the line that says: `0x3: decode OPCODE`. Add a new line and write the following:

```
0x3: decode OPCODE {
// Add your code HERE:
    0x1A: decode FUNCT3 {
        format ROp {
              0x0: decode FUNCT7 {
                    0x01: mod({{ Rd = Rs1_sd % Rs2_sd; }});
              }
        }
    } 
// END of your Code

0x00: decode FUNCT3 {
      format Load {
....
```

As you notice, the opcode is 0x1A, FUNCT7 is 0x01, and FUNCT3 is 0x0 as we defined earlier! the line `format ROp` defines the format of the instruction as an R-type. The tutorial does not use the right numbers for some reason so GEM5 will not be able to detect the instruction correctly.

**Step 2**: build gem5 using the following command and you are done!!

```
$ scons build/RISCV/gem5.opt
```

**Step 3**: After compiler a c code with the riscv compiler that we build earlier, you can run your code with gem5 using the following command assuming that the name of your executable is `main`:

```
$ GEM5 ~/dir/gem5/configs/example/se.py -c ./main
```

You may want to change the default configuration that are used by se.py by passing different parameters for it. For example, the following command uses O3CPU with a memory size of 16GB, memory type is DD4_2400_4x16, L1 data cache size of 64 KB, and L1 instruction cache size of 16 KB.

```
$ GEM5 ~/dir/gem5/configs/example/se.py --cpu-clock=5GHz --cpu-type=O3CPU --mem-size=16GB --mem-type=DDR4_2400_4x16 --l1d_size=64kB --l1i_size=16kB --caches -c ./main
```

I hope this will help anyone trying to add instructions to RISCV. It took me months to work over all of this so I thought it is helpful if someone can put all of this information in one post! Please keep in mind that my answer is written in 2022 and updates to the RISCV compiler and GEM5 are possible so my answer may be outdated in the next few years.